# Mongoose return 10 results sorted by date for every user id in array of ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

lets say we have an array of user ids :

```
    "ids": [
        "623d71c628820d09797be558",
        "62419d6477775214de099838",
        "62419d7877775214de099845",
        "62419d8877775214de09984c"
    ]
```

and we want to return the first 10 documents of every id sorted by date. I know we can do :

```
  const docs = await Model.find({ id: { $in: ids } })
    .sort("date")
    .limit(10);
```

which returns 10 documents sorted by date,but not for every user,how could i return 10 for every one in array ?

** EDIT **

Here's an example document from the `balance` collection:

```json
  {
    "_id": "624a19a0b1cf7d69a5193737",
    "user": {
      "name": "john",
      "id": "623d71c628820d09797be558"
    },
    "description": "chips",
    "amount": 2,
    "type": "expense",
    "date": "2022-04-03T22:03:12.774Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

and a "user" document :

```
{
        "_id": "623d71c628820d09797be558",
        "name": "john",
        "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you’re looking for “distinct”

Comment: @nicael i tried but it seems functions sort() and limit() cannot be used with distinct

Comment: can't find how this can be done , i upvoted so maybe we find an answer.

Comment: You can do it with Loop(forEach). The database layer can be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it using an aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": {
        "$in": [
          "623d71c628820d09797be558",
          "62419d6477775214de099838",
          "62419d7877775214de099845",
          "62419d8877775214de09984c"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { "date": 1 }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "docs": { "$push": "$$CURRENT" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "id": "$_id",
      "docs": { "$slice": [ "$docs", 10 ] }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xJmCHF0NzOL).

Comment: const ids = users.map((user) => user._id)  > these are probably ObjectIds, while in the example the _ids are strings

Comment: it works when i pass the array of user ids hardcoded like this,however when i pass a variable from a different query like : const users = await UsersModel.find();
                                   const ids = users.map((user) => user._id),which returns the same thing,it doesnt return anything,any ideas why that might happen ?

take a look at my code : https://jsitor.com/08voW6Ssv

Comment: @nimrodserok it returns exactly the same thing when i log it

Comment: An example document would have been helpful here.  Do you need to `"$match"` `id`, `_id`, `user.id`, or `user._id` ... or something else?

Comment: console.log an ObjectId prints a string...So this is not the way to test it. It is better to check your schema, or debug, or provide an example document like @rickhg12hs suggested.

Comment: @rickhg12hs sure i included an example document,i want to match user.id,from the array of ids im getting from another query of "users",in a way where it returns first 10 documents sorted by date for every unique user.id...when i pass it a simple array with hardcoded ids,like in the example it works perfectly

Comment: @rickhg12hs no,why ? its an array of user documents,and im returning an array of their _id's

Comment: TBH, I think it would be worth it to redo your question, noting that there are two collections and the result you are trying to achieve.  I believe you can get your desired output by a single query using `"$lookup"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs will probably post a revised one,thank you !